# How find aar library path in Android file system

Tags: android

I included android library(lib.aar) to my Android project. When the application started, I want to check hash of this libraries to understand whether libraries were changed or not. I know shared cpp libraries(.so) located in lib folder, but I can not find android library (lib.aar) in file system. Where aar files are placed in Android file system ?
I used `./adb shell ls -lR | grep "lib.aar"` and `./adb shell find / -name *lib.aar*` and I looked `/data/data/com.test.test` application folder but found nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not gonna find anything with those two commands because you essentially search the system files and not the APKs

Comment: .aar convert to jar after that put into lib folder and add as library

Comment: @RejoylinLokeshwaran I checked '/data/data/com.test.test/lib' but there is no jar in it

Comment: No. Just rename the .aar to .zip and extract the .zip

Answer (score 0):

AOT (ahead-of-time compilation)

i cant find solution. but i can obtain path by another way.

put libraries to assets, and  copy to appincationInfo().dataDir when running.

appincationInfo().dataDir is what i want.

may be help.

Comment: this doesn't shed much light on why this is infeasible